# Cannot display the emoticon value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Textarea cannot preview image so I make it's `background` and `color` **transparent** and a another `div` set behind it to preview textarea's val.

Now, when I click right emoticons icon(In my below example) toggle to show all and click any one of them to add, Its cannot display the emoticon value (Insert transparently only) but submitted. Where is my wrong here please?

Here. If I write something Its display well. But after write on textarea and click to insert any emoticon, Its cannot work also. May be these problem also related with above.

Please help me?

```js
var smileys = {
    ':)': '<img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/public/style_emoticons/default/wacko.png" border="0" alt="" />',
 ':-)': '<img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/public/style_emoticons/default/wacko.png" border="0" alt="" />',
 ':D': '<img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/public/style_emoticons/default/wacko.png" border="0" alt="" />',
};

function smilyMe(msg) {
    msg = msg.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
    for (var key in smileys) {
        msg = msg.replace(key, smileys[key]);
    }
    return msg;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".chat > textarea").bind("keyup", function(e) {
    $(".chat > div").html(smilyMe($(".chat > textarea").val()));
  });
  $('#maintbox').on('keyup',function() {
    $(this).css('height','auto');
    $(this).css('height',Math.max(this.scrollHeight)+'px');
  });
  $('#showhide_emobox').click(function(){
    $('#emobox').fadeToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
  $(".embtn").click(function(event){
    var prevMsg = $(".chat > textarea").val();
    var emotiText = $(event.target).attr("alt");
    $(".chat > textarea").html(prevMsg + emotiText);
  });
    $('textarea').elastic();
});
```

```css
#maintbox {
    position:relative;
 border: 2px solid #ccc;
 min-height: 50px;
 width: 450;
    top:100px;
}
div.chat {
    width: 100%;
}
.preview {
    max-width: 400px;
    font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000000;
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0; z-index:997;
}
div.chat > textarea {
    font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif;
 font-size:14px;
    margin-left:-2px;
    margin-top:-2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
 min-height: 50px;
 width: 510px;
    resize:none;
 float:left;
    position:absolute; color:transparent;
    top:0; left:0; z-index:998; background: transparent;
}
.em {
    position:relative;
    margin:1px 2px;
    float:right;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
.em img {
    margin-top:1px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:white;
    display:block;
    transition:all 1s ease;
}
#emobox {
    background:#fff;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    bottom:25px;
    left:-176px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#emobox img {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="maintbox">
  <div class="chat">
    <div class="preview"></div>
   <textarea name="comment" rows="2" tabindex="4" id="comment" placeholder="Type here..."></textarea>
  </div>
      
<div align="right"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fez/512/FEZ-05-128.png" width="25" alt="" id="uploadMedia" style="padding:2px;cursor:pointer;" />
  <div class="em">
    <img src="http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/big-smile-256x256.png" width="25" id="showhide_emobox"/>
      <div id="emobox">
  <img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/public/style_emoticons/default/wacko.png" alt=":)" class="embtn" />
  <img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/public/style_emoticons/default/wacko.png" alt=":-)" class="embtn" />
  <img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/public/style_emoticons/default/wacko.png" alt=":D" class="embtn" />
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c0d3.googlecode.com/files/jquery-latest.pack.js'></script>
<script src="https://jquery-elastic.googlecode.com/svn-history/r30/trunk/jquery.elastic.source.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you copy the text&emoticon to the preview box only on keyup event of the text area. you need to do it also when you choose an emoticon, just add the following line to the emoticon click handler:

```
$(".chat > div").html(smilyMe($(".chat > textarea").val()));
```

**here is your fixed snippet**

```js
var smileys = {
    ':)': '<img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/public/style_emoticons/default/wacko.png" border="0" alt="" />',
 ':-)': '<img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/public/style_emoticons/default/wacko.png" border="0" alt="" />',
 ':D': '<img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/public/style_emoticons/default/wacko.png" border="0" alt="" />',
};

function smilyMe(msg) {
    msg = msg.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
    for (var key in smileys) {
        msg = msg.replace(key, smileys[key]);
    }
    return msg;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".chat > textarea").bind("keyup", function(e) {
    $(".chat > div").html(smilyMe($(".chat > textarea").val()));
  });
  $('#maintbox').on('keyup',function() {
    $(this).css('height','auto');
    $(this).css('height',Math.max(this.scrollHeight)+'px');
  });
  $('#showhide_emobox').click(function(){
    $('#emobox').fadeToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
  $(".embtn").click(function(event){
    var prevMsg = $(".chat > textarea").val();
    var emotiText = $(event.target).attr("alt");
    $(".chat > textarea").html(prevMsg + emotiText);
     $(".chat > div").html(smilyMe($(".chat > textarea").val()));
  });
    $('textarea').elastic();
});
```

```css
#maintbox {
    position:relative;
 border: 2px solid #ccc;
 min-height: 50px;
 width: 450;
    top:100px;
}
div.chat {
    width: 100%;
}
.preview {
    max-width: 400px;
    font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000000;
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0; z-index:997;
}
div.chat > textarea {
    font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif;
 font-size:14px;
    margin-left:-2px;
    margin-top:-2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
 min-height: 50px;
 width: 510px;
    resize:none;
 float:left;
    position:absolute; color:transparent;
    top:0; left:0; z-index:998; background: transparent;
}
.em {
    position:relative;
    margin:1px 2px;
    float:right;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
.em img {
    margin-top:1px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:white;
    display:block;
    transition:all 1s ease;
}
#emobox {
    background:#fff;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    bottom:25px;
    left:-176px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#emobox img {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="maintbox">
  <div class="chat">
    <div class="preview"></div>
   <textarea name="comment" rows="2" tabindex="4" id="comment" placeholder="Type here..."></textarea>
  </div>
      
<div align="right"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fez/512/FEZ-05-128.png" width="25" alt="" id="uploadMedia" style="padding:2px;cursor:pointer;" />
  <div class="em">
    <img src="http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/big-smile-256x256.png" width="25" id="showhide_emobox"/>
      <div id="emobox">
  <img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/public/style_emoticons/default/wacko.png" alt=":)" class="embtn" />
  <img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/public/style_emoticons/default/wacko.png" alt=":-)" class="embtn" />
  <img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/public/style_emoticons/default/wacko.png" alt=":D" class="embtn" />
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c0d3.googlecode.com/files/jquery-latest.pack.js'></script>
<script src="https://jquery-elastic.googlecode.com/svn-history/r30/trunk/jquery.elastic.source.js"></script>
```